# ARDUINO IDE debug level for stack trace only (nodeMCU 1.0)

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, nodemcu

What is the minimum `debug level` (`TOOLS` tab) which will display the stack trace on crash?

I would like to reduce information clutter in the serial monitor.

I understand that `debug port` must point to my serial monitor.

In case it makes a difference, it is a NodeMCU, running C++, in Arduino IDE on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The crash report is printed to 'standard output' by `__wrap_system_restart_local` in `core_esp8266_postmortem.c` in esp8266 Arduino core.

The standard output is considered as debug output in esp8266 Arduino core. Debug output to hardware Serial can be enabled in runtime by `Serial.setDebugOutput(true);`.

At compile time the initial debug output is controled by `-DDEBUG_ESP_PORT=`, for example `-DDEBUG_ESP_PORT=Serial1`. The Tools menu "Debug port" sets the `DEBUG_ESP_PORT` define. The crash report is not controlled by "Debug level" setting.

Comment: Tks.  Compiles.  Testing.  Is it your evaluation that a question regarding the purposes and effects of `Debug Level` would be appropriate?

Comment: take a look into the boards.txt file in the esp8266 boards package installation folder